# 'manage.py shell' giving syntax error in settings.py

Tags: django

```
File "/home/jc/tryout/mydjangoproject/mydjangoproject/settings.py", line 1
\"""
   ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

my settings.py is :

```
"""
Django settings for mydjangoproject project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'nurokm67=6qezctkfa-o-g+k$=u$nete3pw)d*q!6j_$g7i#0l'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True
```

Comment: Which version of Python do you have?

Comment: Is there _anything_ above the first line you posted?

Comment: To make it simpler you can copy your settings.py into settings.py.tpl and remove all comments from settings.py

Answer (score -1):

I got the same problem, I just write:

```
def__str__(self):
```

instead of

```
def __str__(self):
```

to solve the problem just make a space between `def` and `__str`